# Polymer - Choosing an Iron-Collapse element

Tags: polymer

I'm working my way through Polymer. I'm trying to figure out how to use an `iron-collapse` element within a `dom-repeat`. Currently, I have the following:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[ data ]]" as="child">
  <div class="child-item">
    <div class="info" on-click="_toggleClick">
      <paper-item>
          <iron-icon icon="arrow-drop-up" class="rotate-90"></iron-icon>
          <span>[[ child.name ]]</span>
      </paper-item>
    </div>

    <iron-collapse opened="false">
      <div>Details for child go here</div>
    </iron-collapse>
  </div>
</template>

...

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'child-details',
    properties: {
      data: {
        type: Array,
        value: function() {
          return [];
        }
      },
    },          

    _toggleClick: function(e, detail) {
      try {
        var arrowElement = document.querySelector('iron-icon');
        arrowElement.classList.toggle('rotate-clockwise-90');
      } catch (ex) {
        console.log('Unable to rotate arrow.');
        console.log(ex);
      }         

      try {
        var element = Polymer.dom(parent).querySelector('iron-collapse');
        element.toggle();
      } catch (ex) {
        console.log('Unable to toggle iron-collapse.');
        console.log(ex);
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

When I click on the `div`, I see the following in the console window:

```
Unable to toggle iron-collapse.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined(...)
```

I'm not sure why the `iron-collapse` element is not found. At the same time, the classList toggle is begin applied to the first `iron-icon` element on the page instead of the first `iron-icon` element in the `dom-repeat` like I was expecting. Which I don't understand that either.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selectors

```
document.querySelector('iron-icon');

var element = Polymer.dom(parent).querySelector('iron-collapse');
```

are flawed in several ways.

- the first start from `document` but you want to start from the current element.
- the second starts from `parent` which isn't really better
- you create several `iron-collapse`, what's the point in selecting the first found "anywhere". You want the one that was clicked.

use instead

```
var div = Polymer.dom(e).rootTarget;
div.querySelector('iron-icon').classList.toggle('rotate-clockwise-90')
div.querySelector('iron-collapse').toggle();
```

Comment: When I try the above, I get an error that says: `TypeError: Polymer.event is not a function(...)`. What is that supposed to be? Thank you for your help!

Comment: I updated my answer. I use Polymer only from Dart and there are some differences. See also https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html#retargeting

Comment: Thank you for your persistence. However, that does not work. While the `Polymer.dom` item worked. The next two lines failed. The reason why is because both `querySelector` calls return `null`. When wrapped in `try...catch` blocks, I see these two errors: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null(...)` and `TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of null(...)`.

Comment: Can you check what element exact is returned by the `...rootTarget` line? Can you try `localTarget` instead of `rootTarget`?

Comment: localTarget and rootTarget seem to be the same values. It always comes back as the first `iron-icon` element. I don't understand that. I would expect the `div` to be displayed since that is where the click event handler is at. I"m printing it out using the following: `console.log(Polymer.dom(e).localTarget);' and `console.log(Polymer.dom(e).rootTarget);`

Comment: That's what I expected as well. You can also try just `e.target` or investigate the `e` variable in the debugger. Usually somewhere is a reference to the element with the event listener. I have to admit that I don't fully understand all these targets myself yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the children doesn't have unique id's so I'm using the variable `index` that is generated from the dom-repeat. The index will be the `id` of the div that you got the on-click event on.

I used set that element's id in the event method `_toggleClick` to set a variable `currentOpenedCollapsable`. When it updates, it updates both `opened` on all `iron-collapsables` but also the style sheet on the div container called `child-item`. This latter will make the iron-icon to rotate.

All in all, less javascript code, one added variable, and one added method. Less looping with querySelector, more resuable methods, and more functionality (closing the same element when clicking on it).

```
<style>
  .opened iron-icon {
     transform: rotateZ(180deg);
     transition: transform 0.3s;
  }
</style>

<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[ data ]]" as="child">
  <div class$="child-item [[isOpenedBasedOn(index, currentOpenedCollapsable)]]">
    <div class="info" id="[[index]]" on-click="_toggleClick">
      <paper-item>
          <iron-icon icon="arrow-drop-up"></iron-icon>
          <span>[[ child.name ]]</span>
      </paper-item>
    </div>

    <iron-collapse opened="[[isOpenedBasedOn(index, currentOpenedCollapsable)]]">
      <div>Details for child go here</div>
    </iron-collapse>
  </div>
</template>

...

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'child-details',
    properties: {
      data: {
        type: Array,
        value: function() {
          return [];
        }
      },
      currentOpenedCollapsable: {
        type: Number,
        value: -1
      }
    },          

    // set index, but close (set to -1) if clicking on the same element.
    _toggleClick: function(e) {
      var currentIndex = e.currentTarget.id

      if (this.currentOpenedCollapsable == currentIndex) {
        currentIndex = -1;
      }

      this.set('currentOpenedCollapsable', currentIndex);
    },

    // Using the javascript fact that a filled string is always true while an empty string is always false
    isOpenedBasedOn: function(elementIndex, currentIndex) {
      return (elementIndex == currentIndex) ? 'opened' : '';
    },
  });
</script>
```